# How to remove the ssh tunnel to a remote docker instance

Tags: docker

I followed the instructions on docker's web site to add an SSH tunnel to a remote docker instance and it works great however I don't know how to disconnect it.

The command I ran was: 
`$ ssh -i <path-to-ssh-key> -p <ssh-port> -fNL localhost:2374:/var/run/docker.sock docker@<ssh-host>`

How do I disconnect this ssh connection?  I tried exiting the machine and it didn't unbind the local socket.

Answer (score 0):

try "Ctrl+P+Q"

it should close the connection and keep the container running.

Comment: Are you supposed to press all those keys at once?  Or some sequence?

Comment: The session is running in the background as a task, -f does that.  After hours of research I landed on using -S to create a socket file which then allows you to use the -O cmd-lets to check, exit, etc the session.  The final command I ended up using was: `sudo ssh -i [my-cert] -p [my-port] -M -S [my-socket-file] -fnNT -L localhost:2374:/var/run/docker.sock docker@[my-docker-ip]`.  Then to exit you use the command: `sudo ssh -S [my-socket-file] -O exit docker@[my-docker-ip]`.  The only issue I ran into is that the exit command is returning a non-zero code.  I haven't been able to look into why.

Answer (score 0):

Find the process id of the tunnel, `ps aux | grep ssh`, and kill it, `kill $REPLACEME_WITH_PROCESS_ID`